# connection between 3 raspberry pi via wireless

Tags: python

I have a project to connect 1 raspberry pi 3 model B as a server to 2 raspberry pi zero w via wireless. I tried the code below, but I always get this error in `server.bind('',port)`:

> ```
> socket.error: [Errno 95] oparation not supported
> ```

**server code:**

```
from time import sleep
import socket

lim=2

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port=5555
address=('',port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(2)
con, addr=server.accept
while True:
        data1=con.recv(1234)
        print ("received ", data1, " from first client")
        data2=con.recv(1234)
        print ("received ", data2, " from second client")

        if data1>=lim:
                data1.send("0")
                if data2>=lim :
                        data2.send("0")        
                else:
                        data2.send("1")

        elif data2>=lim:
                data1.send("1")
                data2.send("0")

        elif data1+data2<lim:
            data1.send("1")
            data2.send("1")

        elif data1>=data2:
             data1.send("1")
             data2.send("0")

        else:
            data1.send("invalid")
            data2.send("invalid")

        sleep(2)
server.close()
```

**client code:**

```
from time import sleep
import socket
import requests
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)

client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip='192.168.1.2'
port=5555
address=(ip,port)

client.connect(address)

while True:
    ci=GPIO.input(38)
    client.send(ci)
    co=1

    if co==0:
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)
    elif co==1:
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
            print ("invalid")

    sleep(2)

client.close()
```

in the client code the error in `client.connect(address)`
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the same IP in server side.
Instead of `address=('',port)`
Try `address=('192.168.1.2',port)`. I think this should do it.

Comment: @roubabeainy try 'server.bind(("192.168.1.2", 5555))'